# How do I solve Schrödinger equation with a piecewise periodic Hamiltonian?

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

My Hamiltonian is

```
HI(t) = 
  Piecewise[
    {{H1, n τ <= t <= (n + 1/2) τ}, 
     {H2, (n + 1/2) τ <= t <= (n + 1) τ}}]
```

[image]
where

```
  H1 = {{x, y, 0}, {y, x, 0}, {0, 0, x}}; 
  H2 = {{x, y, z}, {y, x, 0}, {z, 0, x}};
```

Lets take values for numerical solution:

```
x = 2; y = 3; z = 4; z = 4;
```

and

```
n = 20; τ = 0.5;
```

initial condition:

```
{0,1,0};
```

I want to solve the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for the piecewise periodic Hamiltonian:

$$i\frac{\partial\psi(t)}{\partial t}=HI(t)\psi(t)$$

We can also think this problem as

$$i \psi'(t) - HI(t) \psi(t) = 0,$$

where $HI(t)$ is piecewise continuous function.

Comment: Your Hamiltonian isn't hermitian, so it violates probability conservation. Also, you need to specify an initial condition. Then use `NDSolve`.

Comment: Hi Jens, It is not a duplicate question, here I need to deal with Piecewise periodic Hamiltonian which is not state forward. I did not write the Hamiltonian correct previously. Please look at this again, I also define the initial condition as well...

Comment: OK, I posted an answer addressing in particular the `Piecewise` issue. This does indeed look like a separate issue, and since the Hamiltonian is now fixed it's worth keeping as a question in its own right, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think possible issue here was the fact that `Piecewise` is used here to distinguish between different *matrices* inside `NDSolve`. Since `Piecewise` remains unevaluated until you put in specific time values, this hides the matrix structure from `NDSolve` at the initial step where it parses the differential equation.

Also, I think the periodicity you want to achieve is formulated in a way that can't be used in an actual computation, so I would suggest rewriting it with `Mod` instead.

To be on the safe side, I used `MapThread` to put the `Piecewise` inside the matrices (acting element-wise). Then I also defined the solution vector element-wise and used `Thread` in the vectorial differential equation to convert it into a system of equations. Here is the result:

```
H1 = {{x, y, 0}, {y, x, 0}, {0, 0, x}}; H2 = {{x, y, z}, {y, x, 
   0}, {z, 0, x}};

x = 2; y = 3; z = 4; z = 4; n = 20; τ = 0.5;

h[t_] = MapThread[
  Piecewise[{{#1, Mod[t, τ] <= τ/2}, {#2, True}}] &, {H1, 
   H2}, 2]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  2 & 3 & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & (t \bmod 0.5)\leq 0.25 \\
>  4 & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
>  3 & 2 & 0 \\
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & (t \bmod 0.5)\leq 0.25 \\
>  4 & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
>  & 0 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
ψ[t_] = Through[Array["ψ", 3][t]];

sol[t_] = ψ[t] /. 
   First@NDSolve[{Thread[
       I ψ'[t] == h[t].ψ[t]], ψ[0] == {0, 1, 
        0}}, ψ[t], {t, 0, n τ}];

ParametricPlot3D[Re@sol[t], {t, 0, n τ}, PlotStyle -> Tube[.01]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Two comments...(1) If I consider n=0, then the piecewise conditions should be {{H1, 0<= t <= (1/2) τ}, {H2, (1/2) τ <= t <=  τ}}. Can be solve this situation with considering total time =20 τ for the numerical solution. (2) If x is not a constant and I want to plot solution with x for given time. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand point (1) - isn't that what I have already? I used your `n` as the number of periods to follow, so it has no role to play inside the `Piecewise` because `Mod` takes care of subtracting the appropriate integer multiple of $\tau$. For (2), the answer is yes, you can make `x` time dependent without any problem.

Comment: I am little confuse with the mod used in the piecewise. I think it is doing the same thing as shown in my figure. [![enter image description here][1]][1].

Answer (score 0):

It is simple like that:

```
H1 = {{x, y, 0}, {y, x, 0}, {0, 0, x}};
H2 = {{x, y, z}, {y, x, 0}, {z, 0, x}};

x = 2; y = 3; z = 4;
n = 20; \[Tau] = 0.5;
HI[t_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{H1, 
    n \[Tau] <= t <= (n + 1/2) \[Tau]}, {H2, (n + 1/2) \[Tau] <= 
     t <= (n + 1) \[Tau]}}]

NDSolve[{\[Psi][n \[Tau]] == {0, 1, 0}, 
 I \[Psi]'[t] == HI[t].\[Psi][t]}, \[Psi][t]
, {t, n \[Tau], (n + 1) \[Tau]}]
```

Comment: Your method is not working... Could you please till me the solution.